# Set background colour of a html table cell created using a google sheets by google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, background-color

I have created an html table from data in a google sheet using apps script. But I am unable to set the background colour of me created html table. I retrieved background colours of cells in column 2 of the sheet but confused on how to set it in the table through the script. How can I do this?

This is my script file:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("BeneficiaryData");
}

function getTableData() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();
  var i = 2;
  
  for (counter=0; counter<data.length; counter++){
    var bgColour = ws.getRange(i, 2, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getBackground();
    data[counter].push(bgColour)
    //Logger.log(bgColour);
    i++;  
  }
  
  return data;
}
```

From this I'm getting a data set like below. I'm retrieving background colour.

```
[[Name1, Status1, #20cf37], [Name2, Status2, #ffffff], [Name3, Status3, #ffffff]]
```

This is my html file,

```
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">

        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="table-body">
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->

  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData();
        
    });


    function generateTable(dataArray){

      var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

        dataArray.forEach(function(r){

          var row = document.createElement("tr");
          var col1 = document.createElement("td");
          col1.textContent = r[0];     //argument 1
          var col2 = document.createElement("td");
          col2.textContent = r[1];     //argument 2
          col2.style.backgroundColor(r[2]);                              
          row.appendChild(col1);
          row.appendChild(col2);
          tbody.appendChild(row);
          
        });
    }

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

What I tried last was this `col2.style.backgroundColor(r[2]);` in html file but it didn't work. While checking how to set background colour I came across that setBackgroundColor(color) is the method I should be using. But setBackgroundColor is not available for col2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, if the value of `dataArray` is `[["Name1", "Status1", "#20cf37"], ["Name2", "Status2", "#ffffff"], ["Name3", "Status3", "#ffffff"]`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
col2.style.backgroundColor(r[2]);
```

#### To:

```
col2.style.backgroundColor = r[2];
```

Comment: Thank you Tanaike! It worked like charm. How did I miss that.